# Understanding iOS Crash [SIGABRT ABORT]

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt, crashlytics

I just received my first crash report from Crashlytics and am attempting to correct the issue. Unfortunately it is only with a line of code that runs on older devices so I can't test it on my iPhone 6.

The crash report from Crashlytics highlights two threads, the first reads:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[CABasicAnimation altitude]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17734440
```

While the second reads:

```
Crashed: Map Update :: NSOperation 0x1a839470
SIGABRT ABORT at 0x316a3dfc
```

The indicated line of code for both threads is:

```
let relativeAlt = mylocation.altitude - appDelegate.elevation
```

Where:

```
let mylocation = self.mapView.myLocation
let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
```

I'm trying to understand what I'm reading in the crash report. The way I see it the program doesn't understand the `altitude` reference made for some reason? This doesn't make sense to me since this crash seems to occur after that app has been running for several minutes without error, the highlighted line of code is run possibly hundreds of times before the app crashed. What is really happening here?

Additional Information:

Since writing, I have received additional crashes that I believe stem from the same issue:

```
Crashed: Map Update :: NSOperation 0x19fb2d50
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x11d077ca

Crashed: Map Update :: NSOperation 0x145ced50
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x81450a64
```

The first highlighted the following line in my code (I believe since I had worked on the app since this beta release and the line numbers have changed slightly):

```
self.lastLocation = (self.mapView.myLocation as CLLocation).coordinate
```

While the second crash just gave me:

```
libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_msgSend + 5
```

The first of the new crashes (That provided a line of code) provided this report:

```
Thread : Crashed: Map Update :: NSOperation 0x19fb2d50
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3105c708 objc_release + 7
1  FlightTracker                  0x000ba830 FlightTracker.MapViewController.    (locationManager (FlightTracker.MapViewController) -> (Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<ObjectiveC.CLLocationManager>, didUpdateLocations : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.Array<Swift.AnyObject>>) -> ()).(closure #1) (MapViewController.swift:168)
2  Foundation                     0x244ce0fd __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 8
3  Foundation                     0x24438fc5 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 148
4  Foundation                     0x2442b845 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 768
5  Foundation                     0x244d0a57 __NSOQSchedule_f + 186
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x315ad5d9 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 948
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x315ad0a9 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 84
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x315af0d3 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 330
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x315b01fb _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x31720e25 _pthread_wqthread + 668
```

Comment: The exception says that you invoked `altitude` on a `CABasicAnimation` object - which it doesn't support.  This indicates that you have probably invoked the method on a released object and that memory has now been reused for a `CABasicAnimation`.  Where does the `myLocation` property of your map view come from? It isn't a property of `MKMapView`

Comment: `myLocation` is a property of the form `CLLocation!` inherited from the Google Maps iOS API. If the object had been released that might make sense given that the device only had 14MB of RAM available when the device crashed.

Comment: @user3185748 Did you declare `let mylocation` locally within the same method as `let relativeAlt = mylocation.altitude - appDelegate.elevation`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's setup like this: `if let mylocation = self.mapView.myLocation {
                    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
                    if CMAltimeter.isRelativeAltitudeAvailable() {
                    }
                    else {
                        let relativeAlt = mylocation.altitude - appDelegate.elevation
                    }`

Comment: Perhaps force a cast to make sure you're storing the proper type, ex:  if let mylocation = self.mapView.myLocation as CLLocation

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but what does that change then? Even if the app doesn't crash, will altitude then not be recorded for the remainder of the session?

Comment: You're getting this error: `[CABasicAnimation altitude]:` which implies that mylocation is a `CABasicAnimation`. I'm saying that you should make sure it's a `CLLocation` upon declaring it.

Comment: Oh okay, I see what you mean. Thanks for the insight, I'm sure this will only be the beginning in terms of weeding out bugs and weird behaviours! I'll try as you suggested though, have a great evening :)

Answer (score 5):

Probably not your problem, but I just had a SIGABRT that was driving me nuts (that's how I ended up looking at this question) and I'll post my solution in case it helps some future S.O. spelunker.

In my (iPad, not that it matters) app, you can push a button that results in the creation of a not-full-screen `UIViewController` which contains a `UITableView`, and this viewController is presented via `UIPopoverController`.

In my case I had a screw-up in my loading of the tableView items which, at the time of creating the tableView cell I ended up trying to add a null value into a dictionary.  (It's a long story, having to do with an infrastructure class that expects the data to be in a certain format.)

Anyway, attempting to access `newViewController.view` caused the SIGABRT on that line, with no clue that the problem was related to filling the tableView cell.  Nothing tableView-related was evident in the stack trace, so it took me quite a while to narrow things down.  I eventually just guessed "maybe it's the tableview" and disconnected the `IBOutlet` and delegate/dataSource to see if the crash went away.

...And it did.  Which lead me down the path of finding the *real* problem.

Anyway, that's my story.  Hope it's helpful to someone.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the lack of a full/proper crash report and the lack of more code and architecture, the following is an assumption using the little bits of information that are available.

You are accessing a variable in a background thread (NSOperation queue) that got released on another thread and now isn't available any longer, so the pointer shows to some other random object in the memory. And that random object surely has no idea what to do with the `altitude` message which is then causing the crash.

You have to make sure that all variables used in the background thread, are available and not released in another thread.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply. I have merged the questions above. I also provided the stack trace from one of the recent crashes. Also, my understanding is that you can not release an object with Swift, is this correct? If that were to be the case I don't understand how a given variable could disappear on another thread.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I just had another "impossible to track down" solution to this that was driving me bonkers.

Earlier in the day, I'd done a major refactor as some of the objects in my game had names like `RFCFoo` and some were like `RfcBar` and I wanted to standardize the capitalization.

So I used XCode's `Refactor->Rename...` tool, and it worked great, except for one thing:

It failed to rename one specific .xib file, which remained as "RFCBlahBlah.xib" when I was trying to load it as "RfcBlahBlah.xib"

Again, I hope this proves useful for some future SO searcher.