# Identifying Source of iOS Crash

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I've been having a number of similar crashes of my iOS app running on the iPhone 4s and iOS 8.1.2. I'm fairly new at this but I believe that it is crashing due to a lack of memory on the device (3/4 crashes occurred with less than 15MB of free RAM). My app uses Google Map's iOS API to track a users location in the background. When the app is run for longer than 10-15 minutes on this device it crashes and gives me errors such as:

```
Crashed: Map Update :: NSOperation 0x19fb2d50
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x11d077ca

Crashed: Map Update :: NSOperation 0x145ced50
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x81450a64
```

The first highlighted the following line in my code (I believe since I had worked on the app since this beta release and the line numbers have changed slightly):

```
self.lastLocation = (self.mapView.myLocation as CLLocation).coordinate
```

While the second crash just gave me:

```
libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_msgSend + 5
```

Also noteworthy, is that the method that continues to crash is running in a background thread created with `NSOperationQueue()`. I imagine these crashes come about due to a memory leak of some kind which would explain the low memory and why it's a problem on the 4s and not my 6 as of yet. But how should I begin to attack this problem? I can't enable NSZombies since I don't have access to this device and I can't seem to replicate this crash myself. Any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding iOS Crash \[SIGABRT ABORT\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014031/understanding-ios-crash-sigabrt-abort)

Comment: You shouldn't ask the same question twice.

Comment: I apologize, I just thought I might have a better grasp on the greater problem and thought it would be best to start fresh.

Comment: Edit your first question and add details. Your assumption with not having enough memory is wrong anyway. Low memory will cause your app being killed by iOS way before your app knows that there is not enough memory. And such reports look way different.

Comment: Alright, I didn't realize. From what I'd seen it seemed like the logical explanation. I'm sorry for the duplicate question, I see that you have contributed to the previous question, I'll add these details to that one now and follow up.